# Signing a Debugged APK

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, debugging, apk

I used build.phonegap.com to export a `project-debug.apk` and am trying to sign it to push it to Google Play. I changed the .apk to a .zip and then deleted the META-INF folder and then packaged it back to an .apk. I then tried to use jarsigner to resign the .apk and I am getting this message:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is this the wrong approach in trying to sign a debugged APK?

Comment: Why should we delete META-INF folder?

Comment: I'm not sure, I read online that deleting META-INF was best. I still have the original debug.apk.

Comment: Without modifying debug apk follow the steps mentioned in this link to produce signed apk : http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually